# Use an object stored in objectdb file without having it's class definition

Tags: java, objectdb

Let's say I create an object in java named Point with 2 attributes (int x & int y) and i store some instances in an objectdb file. I know how to retrieve all items (as objects) from that file but how can I access their attributes if I don't have the definition of the class Point anymore?

Point definition

```
Class Point {
    int x;
    int y;
}
```

Then I create 2 Points
(0,0)
(1,1)
and store them in objectdb file (i can provide the code if needed)

I retrieve all Point instances with this statement

```
     TypedQuery<Object> query = em.createQuery("SELECT o FROM Object o", Object.class);
     List<Object> results = query.getResultList();
```

Supposedly i only have the objectdb file and not the Point class definition how can i get the values of x and y (even as simple string values)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Only way is to hack your way through the binary serialized version

Comment: So an objectdb file is pretty much useless if it stands alone?

Comment: Without a class definition to use for deserializing, yes

Comment: The comments above are incorrect. The data can be accessed by reflection.

Answer (score 0):

When a class definition is missing ObjectDB automatically generates a synthetic class according to the class schema as stored in the database. Therefore the query in your example returns instances of a synthetic Point class generated by ObjectDB.

You can access your data using the Java Reflection API (possibly using also the JPA Metamodel API).